# Are there limitations how many layers there should be in a geopackage?

Tags: geopackage

Are there limitations how many layers there should be in a geopackage?
It is advantageous to allocate layers into groups to several gqkg, instead of only one gqkg. (I work with approx. 50 layers.)

Answer (score 4):

Looking in the [standard](https://www.geopackage.org/spec120/index.html#_ogc_geopackage_encoding_standard) I can find only one constraint:

> The maximum size of a GeoPackage file is about 140TB. In practice a lower size limit MAY be imposed by the filesystem to which the file is written. Many mobile devices require external memory cards to be formatted using the FAT32 file system which imposes a maximum size limit of 4GB.

So you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for the answer, though
I am more interested in whether it is wise and practical to pack all layers in one fiele, or not.

Comment: Are all your layers related, if so put them in one gpkg otherwise split them up

Comment: Hi Ian, I try to use only one single gqkg and will see how it goes on the length, when i have accumulated experience i review the problem again

Comment: Hi @bernd.dk I just stumbled upon your question here. Any news/experiences about that? I thought it may be dangerous/problematic in case the file is corruptet, as one may loos all layers, instead of just 1, even though I cannot really imagine a szenario where this would happen..